# How can I configure my heroku app for SSL?

Tags: heroku, ssl-certificate, dyno

I would like to configure my heroku app to use SSL (https)

I apparently did something wrong based on the information provided in this link

```
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management
```

here is what I have done thus far:

Changed my dyno to hobby ($7/month now instead of free :-( )  As free dynos cannot have auto certificates enabled.

I then ran this command to verify my domain *(suggested by article)*

```
heroku domains
```

Which gave me:

```
    === instanttiming Custom Domains
    Domain Name           DNS Record Type  DNS Target
    ────────────────────  ───────────────  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
    www.myeventtimes.com  CNAME            descriptive-harbor-<somestuffhere>.herokudns.com
```

I then ran the following to enable automatic certificates *(suggested by article)*

```
heroku certs:auto:enable
```

Which gave me:

```
    Enabling Automatic Certificate Management... starting. 
    See status with heroku certs:auto or wait until active with heroku certs:auto:wait
    === Your certificate will now be managed by Heroku.  Check the status by running heroku certs:auto
```

I then ran the following to see the status of my certificate *(suggested by article)*

```
heroku certs:auto
```

Which gave me:

```
    === Automatic Certificate Management is enabled on instanttiming

    Certificate details:
    Common Name(s): www.myeventtimes.com
    Expires At:     2020-06-30 15:56 UTC
    Issuer:         /C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
    Starts At:      2020-04-01 15:56 UTC
    Subject:        /CN=www.myeventtimes.com
    SSL certificate is verified by a root authority.

    Domain                Status       Last Updated
    ────────────────────  ───────────  ────────────
    www.myeventtimes.com  Cert issued  1 minute
```

At this point, to me anyway, it looks like I have an SSL certificate, so I then went to:

```
httpS:\\MyEventTimes.com
```

and got:

```
    NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

    This server could not prove that it is myeventtimes.com; 
    its security certificate is from shortener.secureserver.net. 
    This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection
```

NOTE:
http://MyEventTimes.com works

What did I miss?

**UPDATE 1**

I ran:

```
heroku certs
```

which gave:

```
    Name               Common Name(s)        Expires               Trusted  Type
    ─────────────────  ────────────────────  ────────────────────  ───────  ────
    apatosaurus-10680  www.myeventtimes.com  2020-06-30 15:56 UTC  True     ACM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow... I did all this stuff and magically... it just worked after "a while"...

So I don't know what else to say.